# Angular service doesn't GET array of objects

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I'm creating a webapp with MEAN stack. In the backend, I have implemented an http get at: "http://localhost:8080/users/friends/"
It works, because I have tried it with Postman and CURL. It returns an array of objects (it returns an array with all the elements of the collection "friends" in the server.

However, in the frontend I have a service with the following function:

```
this.getFriends = function() {
    var q = $q.defer();

    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/users/friends/")
        .then(
            function(friends) {
                q.resolve(friends);
            },
            function(err) {
                q.reject(err);
            }
        );

    return q.promise;
}
```

If I log it, it prints "object Object". The rest of the service is working.

Comment: does server method respond `strigified` json.. do `console.log(friends)` inside your `$http.get` success

Comment: check on the console what that object Object actually is.

Comment: Done. The result of the log in the server is the same array of objects.

Comment: I think Gandalf means for you to log the friends response on the client. Remeber, when getFriends() returns, you are getting a promise object.

Comment: Yep, I was anskering Pankaj Parkar. I've already done the log on the client and it just logs "object Object". How should I do the log to check what object Object actually is?

Comment: Do the log inside your $http then() callback, right where the response data is available. Or just look in your browser developer tools to see the raw JSON.

Comment: It logs: Object {data: Array[19], status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: console.log(friends)

Comment: Done. I just realized that it returns an Object with the array inside ("Object {data: Array[19], status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}"), but I don't know how to get it.

Comment: try friends.data to access the array

Comment: solved! thank you very much, guys

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: if you receive "data", to access the array you have to take "data.data", because the response is an object which contains the array.

Comment: For more information on the response object, see [AngularJS $http API Reference -- General Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage).